# How can I embed a full HTML page [HTML+CSS+JS] into tkinter app

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, electron, chromium

I'm working on a program and trying to display full rendered html into a tkinter app (that includes JS and CSS). I've tried multiple libraries that aims in achieving just that but they all are SOOO limited in functionality and only can render very basic html files for example only some inline CSS and not all, no JS support, no external css support, etc...

So I was thinking if it's possible to have electron (or chromium or a web engin general) does all the rendering and only display the electron window inside of the tkinter app. That way we can ensure correct rendering.

I have very limited knowledge in JS and building this whole thing again using electron and python would be pretty challenging given the time constraint and handling the data flow might get kinda confusing

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: check module `CEF` and [example for tkinter](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tkinter_.py)

Comment: if you need to use HTML+CSS+JS then maybe you should create web page instead of desktop app with tkinter.

Comment: alternatively, you can use electron.js for creating a web app